# Dealing with SOP in GWT/Spring MVC - Rest

Tags: java, spring, spring-mvc, tomcat, gwt

I am implementing the client side of my GWT webapp and I need to interact with a Spring-based web server offering REST APIs. I am communicating via GET and POST by leveraging the DTO pattern. When I deploy the GWT client and the Spring server on the same Tomcat instance, everything works correctly. If I deploy them on two instances, I get HTTP status 0, which is a sign of SOP being applied.

On the server, I implemented and setup a CORS filter:

```
@Component
public class SimpleCORSFilter implements Filter {

public void doFilter(ServletRequest req, ServletResponse res,
        FilterChain chain) throws IOException, ServletException {

    HttpServletResponse response = (HttpServletResponse) res;
    response.setHeader("Access-Control-Allow-Origin", "*");
    response.setHeader("Access-Control-Allow-Methods",
            "POST, GET, OPTIONS, DELETE");
    response.setHeader("Access-Control-Max-Age", "3600");
    response.setHeader("Access-Control-Allow-Headers", "x-requested-with");
    chain.doFilter(req, res);
}

public void init(FilterConfig filterConfig) {
}

public void destroy() {
}

}
```

In the web.xml I put:

```
<filter>
    <filter-name>simpleCORSFilter</filter-name>
    <filter-class>com.lh.clte.web.util.SimpleCORSFilter</filter-class>
</filter>
<filter-mapping>
    <filter-name>simpleCORSFilter</filter-name>
    <servlet-name>rest</servlet-name>
</filter-mapping>
```

On GWT-side, I am building the request this way:

```
protected void sendPost(String url, DTO dto,
        RequestCallback callback) {
    RequestBuilder b = new RequestBuilder(RequestBuilder.POST, url);

    String data = stringify(dto);
    b.setHeader("Content-Type", "application/json");
    b.setHeader("Access-Control-Allow-Origin", "*");
    b.setHeader("Access-Control-Allow-Methods",
            "POST, GET, OPTIONS, DELETE");
    b.setHeader("Access-Control-Max-Age", "3600");
    b.setHeader("Access-Control-Allow-Headers", "x-requested-with");

    b.setRequestData(data);

    b.setCallback(callback);
    try {
        b.send();
    } catch (RequestException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
}

public native String stringify(JavaScriptObject jso) /*-{
    return JSON.stringify(jso);
}-*/;
```

Given all this, what is the best way I can adjust the application to cope with the SOP and allow the deploy on different servers? Thanks.

Comment: Why do you set `Access-Control-Allow` headers in your request? Also `Content-Type` is not set in the response header `Access-Control-Allow-Headers`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Setting the appropriate headers server and client sides fixes the issue:

Server (CORS filter):

```
    HttpServletResponse response = (HttpServletResponse) res;
    response.setHeader("Access-Control-Allow-Origin", "*");
    response.setHeader("Access-Control-Allow-Methods",
            "POST, GET, OPTIONS, DELETE");
    response.setHeader("Access-Control-Max-Age", "3600");
    response.setHeader("Access-Control-Allow-Headers",
            "X-Requested-With,Content-Type");
```

GWT request building:

```
    b.setHeader("Content-Type", "application/json");
```